# MySQL to Postgresql - dividing count with count filter. Experiencing syntax errors

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-migration

I have an issue with this line of the function previous in Mysql I had a similar line -

```
FORMAT(count(ob.`l_id`) / COUNT(CASE WHEN ob.`sts`='XFER' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ),0) as 'DXT'
```

I cant figure out how to translate this to postgresql I've tried a few different things but the line I have at this current moment is below

```
FORMAT(count(*) as total_cas / count(*) filter (where o.scde = 'XFER'),0) AS dxt,
```

Comment: What is the error message you get? The `format()` function makes no sense here. It's used [to format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) "string templates" in Postgres so the first argument needs to be a text/varchar value. What are you trying to there?

Comment: If you trying to round to an integer then Postgres does integer division: `select 1/2; 0`. If you are trying to round a numeric/float value then `select 2/1.25; 1.6000000000000000` --> `select round(2/1.25, 0); 2`. Note if either value is a float/numeric then you get numeric division.

Comment: Error: syntax error at or near "as" Line 9 and the code.

Comment: I need to divide the two counts somehow? Any ideas?